# How to pass data to the views Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ajax

I have form, that send ajax post request to my controller. In my controller I caluculate total price:

```
def price
  @direction = params[:@directions_ids].to_f
  @kind_of_work = params[:kind_of_work].to_f
  @topic = params[:topic].to_f
  @work_discipline = params[:work_discipline].to_f
  @number_of_pages = params[:number_of_pages].to_f
  @deadline = params[:deadline].to_f
  @singularity = params[:singularity].to_f
  @manual = params[:manual]
  @example = params[:example]
  @total_price = @direction*@kind_of_work*@number_of_pages*@deadline*@singularity
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html
  end
end
```

but i cant use it in my form

```
<%= f.hidden_field :total_price, :value => @total_price %>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be clear on what the issue. Make sure to create a Minimal, Verifiable, and Complete example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you create an instance variable in your controller it should appear in your view. Are you sure the `price` method is being executed?

Comment: If it's a ajax request, it's mostly likely that you forget to change the dom after getting the response. And the response would be a json string, so you don't have ERB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, your `price` action is handled by the `POST` request you are making. But you are expecting the instance variable `@total_price` be available in the form.

You need to set the instance variables in the action that renders the form. Not in the action that processes the form.